# Get an element after $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to change a text insert in an div box with jquery. Here is the Code:

```html
<div onClick="$(this span).text('My new Text');" class="switch switch-success" style="float: right;">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>Yes</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to change this "Yes" to "No". Thanks for help ;)

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: Please try something. This is basic DOM traversal.

Comment: This must be a duplicate question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .find method

See a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/41p6nvpj/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onClick="$(this).find('span').text('My new Text');" class="switch switch-success" style="float: right;">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>Yes</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Pass `this` a second parameter which is `context`

   ```
   $('span', this).text('My new Text');
   ```
2. Get `this` element and that use `find` to get `span` in it.

   ```
   $(this).find('span').text('My new Text');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please separate structure, style and function - the CSS, HTML and JS should not be in the same space - its always better to separate the code for better code quality.Also you could do a toggle for the states of the checkbox so that there is different text on the "checked" and "not checked" states.

And you can even do that with CSS

```js
$('.switch').click(function(){
  $(this).find('span').text('My new Text')
})
```

```css
.switch{float: right}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="switch switch-success" >
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>Yes</span>
  </label>
</div>
```